# delete item from userA's recycler view, when userB deletes from the database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

There are two users userA and UserB who are accessing the same collection "DEMO" and there are n documents in it.
userA gets the entire collection and sorts them by "date" field.

```
firestore.collection("DEMO").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(..
{
  @Override
  public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot value, FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
  
   if (value != null) {

     for (DocumentChange doc : value.getDocumentChanges()){ 

       if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

       // When userB adds a document in collection, userA adds it in its recycler view
     
       }
```

now, If userB deletes a document from the collection how do I delete it from userA's recycler view as well?

note: documents in collection are auto ID'd and can be at any position in recycler view

```
--> DEMO--> document 1                               --> Recycler view
        --> document 2                                    item 1    
        --> document 3                                    item 2  // this should get deleted
        --> document 4                                    item 3
        --> document 5 // userB deletes this              item 4
        --> document 6                                    item 5
            .....                                         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `addSnapshotListener` to register your listener, you `onEvent` gets called whenever there's a relevant change to the database.

If a document is removed from the database that `onEvent` had previously been called for, it will be called again with `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED`. So you  can remove it from the UI with:

```
for (DocumentChange doc : value.getDocumentChanges()){ 

  if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
    // When userB adds a document in collection, userA adds it in its recycler view     
  }

  // 
  if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED){
    // Document was removed from the database, so remove it from the UI
  }
```

For Firebase it doesn't matter what user removed the document, it fires the event with `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED` no matter if it's the other user who removed it or if it was removed by the current client.